# Value correlation from multiple tables in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have two tables. One employees and one timesheets

I would like to have correct name at the result but different ID. If you see the result I have the same name everywhere.

How can make the code to fixed my challenge?

Thank you.

[image: Employee SQL]

[image: Timesheet SQL]

[image: Result PHP]

```
In controller I have this code

  
    $profile = ['no' => Auth::user()->no];
    $timesheets = Timesheet::where($profile)->select('*')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();

    foreach ($timesheets as $employee) {
      $emp = ['identification' => $employee->identification];
      $oneemployee = Employees::where($emp)->select('*')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();
    }


    return view('contractor.employees.timesheets', compact('timesheets', 'oneemployee'));


 and in blade I have 

            @foreach ($timesheets as $row1)
             <tr>
               <td>#</td>
                 @foreach ($oneemployee as $row2)
                   <td>{{ $row2->fname}}</td>
                   <td>{{ $row2->lname}}</td>
                 @endforeach
               <td>{{ $row1->identification}}</td>
               <td>{{ $row1->week}}</td>
               <td>{{ $row1->year}}</td>
             </tr>
          @endforeach
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? Display timesheet with thier employee which related timesheet and employee each other with column `identification`. I don't understand what you are doing in the code

Comment: Second row of the result need be Richard Thomas, third row Christopher Anthony, etc. In my code I have same name everywhere

Answer (score 1):

**According to your commit, I suggest the following solution**

If you want dispay timesheet with employees you can use eager loading.
For example:

In your controller:

```
$profile = ['no' => Auth::user()->no];
$timesheets = Timesheet::where($profile)->with("employees")->select('*')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();
return view('contractor.employees.timesheets', compact('timesheets'));
```

In your Timesheet model add hasOne relation to Employee:

```
public function employee(){
 return $this->hasOne(Employee::class,'identification','identification')
}
```

And your view:

```
 @foreach ($timesheets as $timesheet)
   <tr>
     <td>#</td>
     <td>{{ $timesheet->employee->fname}}</td>
     <td>{{ $timesheet->employee->lname}}</td>
     <td>{{ $timesheet->identification}}</td>
     <td>{{ $timesheet->week}}</td>
     <td>{{ $timesheet->year}}</td>
  </tr>
 @endforeach
```